# Uploading a file in S3 using JAVA AWS SDK and getting URL

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using JAVA AWS SDK for uploading a file in Amazon S3.

```
     AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
     s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file));
```

How can I get the URL of S3 where this file has been uploaded ?

I have to send this URL to some function.

say

```
    publish(String url){
    //code to publish that url to some event
}
```

One thing more this will be a continuous process, it can be seen as I have a list of files that I need to put in S3 and every-time I need to send the URL to function `publish(url)`.

Comment: If you go into AWS and find your S3 bucket, it will tell you the URL of that bucket. This might not be a very nice URL (and you might need to add permissions to make entries publically available). You can set up an S3 bucket to be a "statically hosted website" and you can use Route 53 to point a domain name at it.

Comment: I need to use that URL for coding purpose. so I can't do this way.

Comment: You should still be able to find out the base URL of the S3 bucket from the AWS console. The value of any "keys" you put into the bucket will be accessable from http://<THAT URL>/<THE KEY>

Comment: I need to publish that link to some function and I need to automate this process. Every time I can't go to AWS console and copy that URL.

Comment: The S3 bucket will always have the same base URL. (i.e. something like http://s3.aws.92898435/398565396 or something) to get an item with the key "my/file.txt", you need to use http://s3.aws.92898435/398565396/my/file.txt

Comment: ok. so you mean to say suppose I have made a bucket bucket and put a file myfile.txt in it. and lets assume url of bucket is s3.aws.something.bucket1 so If i want to get link where myfile is stored. Will it be s3.aws.something.bucket1/myfile.txt  ??

Comment: yes, it should be something like that

Comment: okay.. thanks.. I will try the same thing.